# Why is animated SVG not used for streaming cartoons?

Tags: video, video-quality

Considering that, per https://video.stackexchange.com/a/18726/34808, animated `.SVG` can be used (even across the internet, via browsers) as a vectoral video format, why are cartoons not served to the user in this format?

Surely it would be significantly more efficient for the distribution company (Crunchyroll, Funimation, etc.) and a superior experience for those with high-resolution displays and/or slow internet connections?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons.

1. Anime and cartoons are not created for the web.
   They are mostly created for TV and broadcasted there, and TV simply don't support SVG most of the time.
2. Even today, Anime is mostly drawn. So SVGs would be require fitting to the source image.
   This process is prone to errors and artifacts, and usually doesn't look that good.
   Some of them use 3D or 2D models, but they still require rendering, therefore the same limitation applies.
3. SVGs require quite a bit of math to render on the client, so streaming the latest episodes on your phone would be extremely wasteful and probably impossible.
4. SVGs are extremely limited in supported shapes and colorization.

The only way to get rid of the limitations of SVGs and make it work in this context, would be to send about 2 million tiny rectangles.
We could call them pixels, which brings me to my last point:

5. SVGs are extremely wasteful. Normal video is compressed to save bandwith, SVG uses big shapes and options for customization to optimize.

```bash
<rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" />
```

This is the simplest rectangle in SVG i know of. You could use 2'000'000 of these for your initial frame.
Add attributes for coloring and you have your first frame.
Then continue by adding animations.
That would require about 60Mb for your first frame (if it's completely black).
SVG would be producing the amount of data Crunchyroll uses for an episode, but within a couple of frames.

Edit:
SVG simply has different applications than video.
Modern containers and codecs are highly optimized toward video production, while svg excels in simple shapes and logos.
I would shake my had and walk out if the graphics designer would bring me the new logo as a png.
And I would do the same if an Animation studio would provide me with animated SVGs as videos

Comment: Thanks, lots. That was quite concrete.

Answer (score 0):

- https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/16v8xa6/comment/k2pj6xh/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

  > Anime isn't drawn with vectors. You would need to reinvent every animator, studio workflow just to make happen what you are proposing.
- https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/16v8xa6/comment/k2pj6xh/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

  > Anime is not produced with vector images. It would look no different in high res screens.